# ReactNative and 64 bit support

Tags: android, react-native, 64-bit

starting from react-native version 0.59 react native provided support for 64 bit. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/#updated-jsc-means-performance-gains-and-64-bit-support-on-android

Though my application is using old react native version (0.39) and upgrading to 0.59 is very huge task.
After August 1, 2019 I will not be able to update app in google play store if my app didn't support 64 bit CPUs.

This is very serious matter. Does anyone have any workarounds?

Comment: Only solution I can found is upgrading to 0.59
 https://github.com/zulip/zulip-mobile/issues/3323 
which is released on March 12, 2019

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814

Comment: Does anyone know if I will be able to submit a new release after Aug 1st if that release supports 64 bit? Or will I not be able to update my app at all. Thanks!

Comment: so finally to fix we have to upgrade react native apps to latest version as there is no other option